# Given string representing a type, get its zero value in golang

Tags: go

Im not too faimilar with golang reflection, and I came across a parsing issue where I try to parse a given string representing a value/struct, to its zero value.
For example:

```
"string" -> ""
int -> 0
[]string -> []string{}
map[..]... -> map[..]...{}
```

anything else that is probably an interface/struct -> interface{} or struct{}
Is there a generic way to determine that using the reflect library?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Zero ? interface{} zero value is nil. see more at https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types

Comment: There's no way to map a string to a type via reflection, and if you don't use a type in your code it likely won't exist in the compiled output. You need to make a map of the types you're interested in yourself.

Comment: There is no way to reflect an input to a type ? automating a `if typeof(..) == int { val := 0 }` kind of thing?